# Error With Summation Formula

Tags: math-mode

Below is the code I use:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{eqnarray}
 \[ E_{n} = \dfrac{1}{N}   \sum_{m}^{}[x(m)w(n-m)]^{2}\]
\end{eqnarray}
\end{center}
```

However it produces many errors, and it does not give the equation a number. All equations before this were automatically assigned a number. However, this one does not have a number and produces many errors. The errors are:

> Bad math environment delimiter. [ Missing \endgroup inserted.

> ...rac{1}{N} \sum_{m}^{}[x(m)w(n-m)]^{2}] Missing } inserted.

> ...rac{1}{N} \sum_{m}^{}[x(m)w(n-m)]^{2}] \begin{eqnarray} on input

> line 344 ended by \end{equation*}. ...rac{1}{N}

> \sum_{m}^{}[x(m)w(n-m)]^{2}]

> Missing $ inserted. ...rac{1}{N} \sum_{m}^{}[x(m)w(n-m)]^{2}]

And many more like these. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using both `\begin{eqnarray}` and `\[`, both of which start math mode. Remove the `\[` and `\]`. But you shouldn't use eqnarray either for reasons stated [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray). You don't seem to using an array of equations, so just use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` perhaps?

Comment: Also the `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` doesn't do anything here but make the spacing worse. Remove that too.

Comment: @frabjous thanks a lot it is finally fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you have really *many* errors and that looking at an introductory manual is needed. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8477/4427 for some pointers.

1. Math displays are centered by default, so `center` does almost nothing; almost in the sense that it does bad, because it marks an allowed page break point, which instead is not allowed before a math display.
2. `eqnarray` is deprecated and, in any case, it shouldn't be used for a single equation/formula.
3. `eqnarray` and the better environments defined by `amsmath` *already* initiate display math mode, so `\[` is illegal inside them.

Just remove the wrong parts and use `equation` for the single equation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    E_{n} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{m}[x(m)w(n-m)]^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your editing.